# Reading the data of a received SMS, using Next13

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I have created a webhook in the Twillio console and it calls my file every time my Twillio number receives an sms text message. However, I am unable to read the actual data so that I can store the 'from' and 'body' of the sms in my 'addMessage' function (the value of from and body gets stored as 'undefined). This is my code, the console.log(req.body) prints 'ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }':

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { addMessage } from '../../messageStore';



export async function POST(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

// Get message body and sender's number from the request body
const body = req.body.Body;
const from = req.body.From;

console.log(req.body);

// Add the new message to the messages array
addMessage({ body, from });

return NextResponse.json(res);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like req.body is a stream that needs to be read and not the actual contents. You might be able to read it like this (untested):

```
export async function POST(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const body = await req.json();
    console.log(body);
}
```

Comment: 'Property 'json' does not exist on type 'NextApiRequest'

Comment: Alright, how about req.text() does that return anything? Do you have control over the request sent from Twilio? From next.js docs: "req.body - An object containing the body parsed by content-type, or null if no body was sent". If you are able to set the content type where the request is sent you could try that.

Comment: Here's another option that might work: const body = await new Response(req.body).json(); (or ....text();)